# Google places API return a single type "car_repair"

Tags: java, android-studio, google-places-api

I'm using Google places API and it is returning all the places in my location. However I only want it to return a type for "car-repair" I think I nearly have it but I'm missing something if anyone could guide me in the right direction it would be great :)

My Code so far
PlacPickerActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class PlacePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=car_repair&key=AIzaSyBKsTtLyMBQH8mhvbknJ4MvZwACotmeYO0";

    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mAttributions;
    private TextView mNumber;
    private static final LatLngBounds Sligo = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(54.27, -8.47), new LatLng(54.27, -8.47));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
        pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(Sligo);

                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                        | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            final CharSequence formatted_phone_number = place.getPhoneNumber();
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }

            mName.setText(name);
            mAddress.setText(address);
            mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));
            mNumber.setText(formatted_phone_number);


        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.truiton.placepicker">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBKsTtLyMBQH8mhvbknJ4MvZwACotmeYO0"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".PlacePickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I type in the URL into my browser on my PC it returns all the type "car_repair" in my area therefore my API Key does work
[image]

Comment: google does not provide you with any result with keyword 'car repair' . so you just can't get this result directly from places api. you have to do it yourself.

Comment: According to this it does https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Answer (score 4):

Try with a query similar to this:
Location is in format latitude,longitude...and be careful is "types" not type.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=54.27,-8.47&radius=1000&types=car_repair&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Comment: I will take a look and I will get back to you

Comment: I have the url string `String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=54.27,-8.47&types=car_repair&radius=5000&key=AIzaSyANj6qV9bJGYr0i-Cj5u2I4TvOCOvQRqq4&sensor=true";` do I need to return this url somewhere to get a result?

Comment: It looks like is some problem with your api key {
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address XXXXXXXX, with empty referer",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: I added an image of what I get using this url `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=54.27,-8.47&radius=1000&types=car_repair&key=AIzaSyANj6qV9bJGYr0i-Cj5u2I4TvOCOvQRqq4&sensor=true`

Comment: Oh well you get the info...This is the json with the info you requested, you need to parse it  and show it or convert it to objects to work with...

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm new with android could you point me in the right direction on what I need to do because I'm so confused here. Thanks

Comment: Sure ...You can use Volley, take a look at this link, is a library commonly used for url requests :  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: You also have this post that talks about another simplier way of getting the http response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106841/discussion-between-craig-gallagher-and-jonhid).

Answer (score 2):

Because this API return the place type inside a scope. There is a method may improve the result but still not optimal, which is called `setLatLngBounds`.The link is https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker.IntentBuilder#public-method-summary
I have tried this API before and find it is totally a mess in some degree. 
For example, if you want to find restaurant inside a university, this API will not only return you the restaurant but also many other types like `University`. Setting a bound maybe be good but still get annoying result if you only use the API.
If you just want the type of `car-repair`, I suggest you write a filter to filter other types and only keep car-repair type and relevant information.

Comment: I will take a look and I will get back to you

Comment: Any idea how I would create this filter

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared this for you , hope it helps

```
 // A class to store your results
 public class Place {
     private String icon;
     private Double latitude;

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon=icon;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude=latitude;
    }

    // .....
}

// Utility class to keep things simple
public class Functions {

     public static JSONObject convertInputStreamToJSONObject(InputStream inputStream)
        throws JSONException, IOException 
   {
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
       String line = "";
       String result = "";
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
           result += line;

       inputStream.close();
       return new JSONObject(result);

   }

   public static ArrayList<Place> parsePlacesFromJson(JSONObject datos) throws JSONException {

       List<Place> placesList = new ArrayList<>();

       // in your case this must be "results" I think
       final int LIST_LENGTH = datos.getJSONArray("results").length();
       //final int LIST_LENGTH = datos.getJSONArray("nameOfTheJsonMainArray").length();

       Log.d("Length", String.valueOf(LIST_LENGTH));


       // For every element in the list
       for(int i = 0; i < LIST_LENGTH; i++) {

           // Instance of a new Place
           Place place = new Place();

           // Get data as needed, this represents one place
           JSONObject obj = datos.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i);

           Double latitude = obj.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
           String icon = obj.getString("icon");

           place.setLatitude(latitude);
           place.setIcon(icon);
           //....
           placesList.add(place)

       }

       return placesList;
   }
 }

// The google places reader class
public class ApiReader {


   private static final String TAG = "API_READER";
   Context context;
   View v; 

   public ApiReader(Context context, View v) {
       this.context = context;
       this.v = v;
   }


   private static final String APIKEY = "yourkeyhere";


   private static String ENDPOINT =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=54.27,-8.47&radius=1000&types=car_repair&key=%s";



   // Method to be called 
   public void getCarRepairs() throws IOException {
       URL url = new URL(String.format(ENDPOINT, APIKEY));
       new GetPlaces().execute(url);
   }




   // Inner asyctask class 
   private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, List<Place>> {
       List<Place> lista;
       @Override
       protected List<Place> doInBackground(URL... params) {
           JSONObject datos;
           URL url = params[0];
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


           try {
               urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
               datos = Functions.convertInputStreamToJSONObject(in);
               Log.i(TAG, datos.toString());

                 // De los datos obtenemos un objeto Place

               lista  = Functions.parsePlacesFromJson(datos);
               Log.i(TAG, "" + lista.toString());
               Log.i(TAG, "Went into try was OK.");

           } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Went into catch");

           } finally {
               urlConnection.disconnect();
               Log.i(TAG, "Went into finally, urlConnection disconnected.");
           }

           return lista;
       }


       // This method it gets what the "doInBackGround" returns
       protected void onPostExecute(List<Place> placesList) {

           if(placesList != null) {

               // Do whatever with the list of places
               //Functions.updateView(v, placesList);

           }
       }
   }

 }

 // And to make things work in yout activity just do like this

        ApiReader api = new ApiReader(this, findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));

        try {
            api.getCarRepairs();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Enjoy !!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will give this a shot I'm pretty new to android so this may take me a while to get right.

Comment: Did this code work for you as it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Whats the problem.. you have a placeList not null in the onPostExecute method??

Comment: I have many errors on my GetPlaces Class is there anyway you could put this code up on Github so I can see the way you would lay it out please. I'm sorry for being a nuisance but I'm a newbie at android development and I really need this to work. I'm using Android Studio by the way. Thanks

Comment: Can you send me the link to the Github repository. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106840/discussion-between-jonhid-and-craig-gallagher).