# Google Places API get certain type "Car-Repair"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I'm making an application in Android Studio where the user can find all the mechanics in their area. I'm using google places to accomplish this currently I'm able to find all the nearby places in my area, however I can't seem to filter the type to "Car_Repair". Can anyone help me with this issue please.

PlacePickerActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PlacePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=car_repair&key=AIzaSyB86znUFrlT9mNC8xm00Jc2-AirUU9U_2I";

    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mAttributions;
    private TextView mNumber;
    private TextView car;
    private static final LatLngBounds Sligo = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(54.27, -8.47), new LatLng(54.27, -8.47));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
        pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(Sligo);
                    List<Integer> filterTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    filterTypes.add(Place.TYPE_CAR_REPAIR);


                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                        | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            final CharSequence formatted_phone_number = place.getPhoneNumber();

        //    final CharSequence car = place.TYPE_CAR_REPAIR();
           //public abstract List<Integer> getTypeFilter(place.TYPE_CAR_REPAIR);
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }

            mName.setText(name);
            mAddress.setText(address);
            mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));
            mNumber.setText(formatted_phone_number);



        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.truiton.placepicker">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB86znUFrlT9mNC8xm00Jc2-AirUU9U_2I"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".PlacePickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google places API return a single type "car\_repair"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060373/google-places-api-return-a-single-type-car-repair)

Comment: There's no point posting a basically identical question to your previous question.  This new posting offers no new information (e.g. the code is the same aside from trivial differences), and so it's not likely to attract any better result for you than the first time you asked, and it makes other truly new questions harder to discover.  I'm glad you've tried adding a bounty to the earlier question, that seems like a better strategy for you.